# Is there a DAX function that takes Year, Month, and Week Number as inputs and then return a Date corresponding to the inputs?

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a Table which my weekly report fetches data from. The Table is updated every week, so the data are in form of Week 1, Week 2,..., Week 5. I have other date information such as Year, and Month, but no specific days.

With this available information, I hope there is a DAX function (FUNC) that will take Year, Month, and Week number and return the corresponding weekend date.

Say, For March 2024 Week 2, I can have something like:

```
FUNC (2024,03,02) = DATE (2024,03,09)
```

Below is what I have tried.

Since there's no date column from the data, so I introduced a surrogate date that takes Year, Month and takes 1 (Constant) for day.

So, if week 3 February 2024 data is to be added to the Table,
the derived date will be `DATE (2024,02,01)` .

The limitation with this is that I cannot accurately carry out month-on-month, quarter-on-quarter, and year-on-year calculations, as the date is always pointing to first day of the month.

[image: Sample Table]